# Valgrind yells about uninitialised value written

Tags: c, valgrind

this function fills an array dinamically generated with data read from a file. Valgrind yells this:

```
==21124== Syscall param write(buf) points to uninitialised byte(s)
==21124==    at 0x410D013: write (in /lib/libc-2.13.so)
==21124==    by 0x8049839: main (mmboxd.c:437)
==21124==  Address 0x41b49e6 is 6 bytes inside a block of size 344 alloc'd
==21124==    at 0x4026D0E: realloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==21124==    by 0x8049924: messagesList (mmboxd.c:468)
==21124==    by 0x80497F1: main (mmboxd.c:432)
==21124==
```

The write function is called by realloc I guess,but the struct realloc is writing is filled in every field. What's wrong?
Here the function, the scruct and the main segment where it is called:

```
typedef struct 
{
char sender[41], recipient[41];   /* mittente e destinatario */
char obj[41], date[41];           /* oggetto e data del messaggio */
char flags;                       /* letto o no,marcato o no per la cancellazione */
size_t size;                      /* dimensione in bytes del corpo del messaggio */
} mmbox_mail_complete;

mmbox_mail_complete *messagesList(char *username, int *nmails)
{
/* NB - MAILBOX è così composta: 6 righe per ogni messaggio -->  1 mittente, 2 oggetto, 3 data, 4 flags, 5 size, 6 messaggio */
mmbox_mail_complete *mails = NULL;   /* array di mail */
int n = 0;                           /* dimensione dell'array di mail */
int input;                           /* carattere letto */
char line[40];                       /* linea letta */
int k;                               /* contatore */
FILE *file;                          /* puntatore al file da leggere/scrivere */    

/* apro il file dell'utente */
if(!(file = fopen(userPath(username), "r")))   logMmboxd("failed opening user mailbox\n", 1);
else                                           logMmboxd("succeded in opening user mailbox\n", 0);

/* leggo una riga alla volta appunto a partire dalla seconda e la stipo */
while((input = fgetc(file)) != EOF)   
{  
    /* riavvolgo di un carattere avanzato nel caso non fosse EOF nella condizione del ciclo */
    if(fseek(file, -1, SEEK_CUR) == -1)   logMmboxd("failed seeking mailbox\n", 1);
    else                                  logMmboxd("seeked mailbox\n", 0);

    /* alloco una nuova mail */
    mails = realloc(mails, sizeof(mmbox_mail_complete) * (n+1));
    n++;

    /* leggo il mittente */
    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   mails[n-1].sender[k] = input; 
    mails[n-1].sender[k] = '\0';    

    /* leggo il mittente (in realtà ce l'ho gia in username) */
    for(k=0; username[k] != '\0'; k++)   mails[n-1].recipient[k] = username[k]; 
    mails[n-1].recipient[k] = '\0'; 

    /* leggo l'oggetto */
    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   mails[n-1].obj[k] = input; 
    mails[n-1].obj[k] = '\0';   

    /* leggo la data */
    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   mails[n-1].date[k] = input; 
    mails[n-1].date[k] = '\0';

    /* leggo il flag */
    input = fgetc(file);
    mails[n-1].flags = input;
    input = fgetc(file);

    /* leggo la dimensione del messaggio */
    for(k=0; (input=fgetc(file)) != '\n' && input != EOF; k++)   line[k] = input; 
    line[k] = '\0';
    mails[n-1].size = atoi(line);   

    /* mando avanti il puntatore nel file della lunghezza del messaggio */
    if(fseek(file, mails[n-1].size+1, SEEK_CUR) == -1)   logMmboxd("failed seeking (size) mailbox\n", 1);
    else                                                 logMmboxd("seeked mailbox\n", 0);
}
*nmails = n;

fclose(file);
return mails;
}


 /* in the main: the response struct is already memset to 0 */
response.result = SUCCESS;
mails = messagesList(users[k].username, &response.num);
response.num2 = 0;
response.size = sizeof(mmbox_mail_complete) * response.num;
answer(&response, mails);           /* 437 line */
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not writing the entire field for the sender/recipient names, but only until the first NUL byte. While your program is probably going to operate correctly if the bytes following the NUL terminator are not initialized, valgrind cannot know that this is a string and that these bytes are irrelevant.

Comment: asap ill try a memset on the struct after the realloc and before writing on it